# printing a float value just besides of a range of floating values

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

Experts, i want to print a range of values with steps 1.5, and after that i want another float value (10.0) to be print just beside the result of first function .In order to do that i tried the below code but it throws error like TypeError: object of type 'numpy.float64' has no len():  I donot know where i am doing wrong.Thanks.

```
import numpy as np

for x in np.arange(1.0,10.0,1.5):
    print(x)
    
print ('10' * len(x))
```

i expect output like

```
1.0  10.0
2.5  10.0
4.0  10.0
5.5  10.0
7.0  10.0
8.5  10.0
```

Comment: `for x in np.arange(1.0,10.0,1.5): print(x, 10.0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
import numpy as np
for x in np.arange(1.0, 10.0, 1.5):
    print(x, 10.0)
```

Comment: how to save the output to a file @Daisuke